# CSS change only background color for a button

Tags: html, css

Following code, buttons different only by one style setting, produces dramatically different button looks. Not only is the background color changed, but also the border style, rounded corners, and gradient. I guess losing the gradient isn't too surprising, but the others are, to me. Can anyone explain why?  Output of following code is viewable [here](http://nevcal.com/temporary/test-button.html).  I found lots of "solutions" for how to style the button like the default, but why does the default change so dramatically when just trying to change the background color?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="favicon-index.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>test buttons</h1>
<input type="button" value="gradient">
<input type="button" value="background-color" style="background-color: #ff0;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do something how browser renders them. When no styles are applied it uses the native os style. But when style is applied it must draw it from the beginning. since you are only setting the background value, the border and other style attributes are used from browser defaults.

On every os and browser the native buttons look a little different, but with same styles they look the same.